# How to get extra content in a running activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onresume

I want to send the text entered by the user from current activity (which is **LIKE A DIALOG BUT NOT ONE**). Activity 1 is in the background and running.
I have attempted this as of now:

Second Activity Code:

```
 submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            if(companyNameEditText.getText().toString()!=null) {
                intent.putExtra("companyName", companyNameEditText.getText().toString());
                 nameChanged=true;
                finish();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ChangeNameActivity.this,"Please enter a value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

onDestroy for second Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(nameChanged)
    {
        activityFinishedWithChanges= true;
    }
}
```

First Activity's on Resume:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(ChangeNameActivity.activityFinishedWithChanges) {
        companyNameText = findViewById(R.id.companyNameText);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("companyName")) {
            String companyName = getIntent().getStringExtra("companyName");
            if (companyName != null) {
                if (!companyName.equals("")) {
                    companyNameText.setText(companyName);
                    AppUtils.setNameSharedPreference(BrandSettingsActivity.this, AppConstants.organizationName, getIntent().getStringExtra("companyName"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a null value in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current aproach doesn't work, because your created Intent which you are using to retrieve the company name isn't used in any way.

You should use the `ActivityResult` functionality of the ActivityClass. The basic conecept works like this:

First you start an activity with the request to return a result with [Context.startActivitForResult(Intent,requestCode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)). The new activity is started and has the oppurtunity to do stuff. When the new activity has retrieved a result it sets its result with [Context.setResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) and finish itself afterwards.
When the new Activity is finished the function [Activity.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) is called with the same requestCode, defined in [Context.startActivitForResult(Intent,requestCode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and the data and resultCode defined in [Context.setResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)).

The official documentation recommends to use a more high level api: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result